# Change Netfly npm-registry for using third-party dependencies

Tags: npm-registry

I'm using some third-party dependencies hosted on a corporate npm-registry (accessible publically) that fails my angular's app deployment

Is there a way to configure npm for Netfly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to override the default npm-registry is to commit your local .npmrc config file in the repo